# Using PatternSequence and __ / Repeated[]

Tags: pattern-matching

I'm trying to scrape [*this*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deaths_in_2019#July) Wikipedia page (*'Deaths in 2019- July', I'm writing this on the 14th.*). I am failing miserably and I'm starting to think that it is due to some misconception on my part on the use of patterns.

Namely, the use of `__` vs `..` and `PatternSequence`.

Please help.

I use `Import[<URL>, "XML"]` to import the page. I use `pattn0` (see below) to identify the positions `pos0 = Position[<XML>, pattn0]` and `pos1 = MapAt[# + 1 &, pos0, {All, -1}]`.

`pos` and `pos1` are used to identify the positions of the desired entries.

I'm using `src = Apply[Part[<XML>, ##] &, Riffle[pos0, pos1], 1]` in all pattern matching attempts as the source over which I try to extract (or match against) parts I want.

(I provide a link to the `src` used, at the end of the question)

### Snippet of desired entries

I will report below a random pair of entries I am interested in:

```
XMLElement["h3", {}, {XMLElement["span", {"class" -> "mw-headline", "id" -> "14"}, {"14"}]}],

XMLElement["ul",{},{
  XMLElement["li",{},{
    XMLElement["a",{"href"->"/wiki/Hussain_Muhammad_Ershad","title"->"Hussain Muhammad Ershad"},{"Hussain Muhammad Ershad"}],", 89, Bangladeshi military officer and politician,",
    XMLElement["a",{"href"->"/wiki/Chief_of_Army_Staff_(Bangladesh)","title"->"Chief of Army Staff (Bangladesh)"},{"Chief of Army Staff"}],"(1978\[Dash]1986) and",
    XMLElement["a",{"href"->"/wiki/President_of_Bangladesh","title"->"President of Bangladesh"},{"President"}],"(1983\[Dash]1990), myelodysplastic syndrome.",
    XMLElement["sup",{"id"->"cite_ref-1","class"->"reference"},{XMLElement["a",{"href"->"#cite_note-1"},{"[1]"}]}]
   }
  ],
XMLElement["li",{},{
    XMLElement["a",{"href"->"/wiki/Nereo_Laroni","title"->"Nereo Laroni"},{"Nereo Laroni"}],", 76, Italian politician,",
    XMLElement["a",{"href"->"/wiki/Mayor_of_Venice","title"->"Mayor of Venice"},{"Mayor of Venice"}],"(1985\[Dash]1987) and",
    XMLElement["a",{"href"->"/wiki/Member_of_the_European_Parliament","title"->"Member of the European Parliament"},{"MEP"}],"(1989\[Dash]1994), complications from heart surgery.",
    XMLElement["sup",{"id"->"cite_ref-2","class"->"reference"},{XMLElement["a",{"href"->"#cite_note-2"},{"[2]"}]}]
   }
  ],
XMLElement["li",{},{
    XMLElement["a",{"href"->"/wiki/Lavenia_Padarath","title"->"Lavenia Padarath"},{"Lavenia Padarath"}],", 74, Fijian politician,",
    XMLElement["a",{"href"->"/wiki/Parliament_of_Fiji","title"->"Parliament of Fiji"},{"MP"}],"(1999\[Dash]2001, 2006) and President of the",
    XMLElement["a",{"href"->"/wiki/Fiji_Labour_Party","title"->"Fiji Labour Party"},{"Labour Party"}],"(since 2015).",
    XMLElement["sup",{"id"->"cite_ref-3","class"->"reference"},{XMLElement["a",{"href"->"#cite_note-3"},{"[3]"}]}]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

### Patterns I-*am trying to*-use

I am using the following patterns to match the entries I am interested in:

```
pattn0 = XMLElement["h3", _, {
   XMLElement["span", {"class" -> "mw-headline", "id" -> id_}, {idnm_}]
  }
 ]
```

(*`pattn0` matches against the day numbers reported in the header for each day*)

and

```
pattn1 = XMLElement["a", {"href" -> href_, Longest[othr___], "title" -> tit_, last___}, {nm_}];
pattn2 = PatternSequence[pattn1, Longest[cmnt___]];
```

- `pattn2` is used to match against entries like `XMLElement["a", {__}, {_}]` which are the data entries I'm (mostly) interested in.
- In `pattn2` I am using `Longest[othr___]` because there are some entries where, between `"href"` and `"title"`, there interjects some other minor entry (some `XMLElement[__]`).
- Also, `last___` is there to match against any remaining entries I might have missed.
- Lastly, `Longest[cmnts___]` is used to match against entries (usually, as far as I can tell, a single one) after `XMLElement["a", __]`.

`pattn3` and `pattn4` match against reference entries:

```
pattn3 = XMLElement["a", {"href" -> href2_}, {refn_}];
pattn4 = XMLElement["sup", {"id" -> id_, "class" -> "reference", {pattn3}];
```

(*`pattn4` is used to match against `XMLElement["sup", {__, {__}]` which are the entries related to references and their links*)

`pattn5` combines all the patterns into one (unfortunately non-performing) pattern:

```
pattn5 = PatternSequence[pattn0, x : XMLElement["ul", _, {XMLElement["li", _, {pattn2 .., pattn4}] ..}]];
```

### Things that work

- Retrieving day numbers
  Evaluating `Cases[src, pattn0 :> idnm]` works! and returns the day numbers

  > ```
  > {14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}
  > ```

  as expected.
- Retrieving footnotes/references

  Both `pattn3` and `pattn4` work. Here, evaluating `Cases[src, pattn4, Infinity]` works (first five results):

  > ```
  > { 
  >     XMLElement[sup,{id->cite_ref-1,class->reference},{XMLElement[a,{href->#cite_note-1},{[1]}]}],
  >     XMLElement[sup,{id->cite_ref-2,class->reference},{XMLElement[a,{href->#cite_note-2},{[2]}]}],
  >     XMLElement[sup,{id->cite_ref-3,class->reference},{XMLElement[a,{href->#cite_note-3},{[3]}]}],
  >     XMLElement[sup,{id->cite_ref-4,class->reference},{XMLElement[a,{href->#cite_note-4},{[4]}]}],
  >     XMLElement[sup,{id->cite_ref-5,class->reference},{XMLElement[a,{href->#cite_note-5},{[5]}]}],...}
  > ```

### Things that partially work

- `pattn2`

  In using `pattn2` I get partially matched results; namely, the part related to `Longest[cmnt___]` does not get matched, ever!. Essentially what works seems to be the part related to `pattn1`.

  ```
  Cases[src, pattn2, Infinity]
  ```

  evaluates to the partially correct result (only the first five entries shown here to avoid clutter)

  > ```
  > {
  > XMLElement[a,{href->/wiki/Hussain_Muhammad_Ershad,title->Hussain Muhammad Ershad},{Hussain Muhammad Ershad}],
  > XMLElement[a,{href->/wiki/Chief_of_Army_Staff_(Bangladesh),title->Chief of Army Staff (Bangladesh)},{Chief of Army Staff}],
  > XMLElement[a,{href->/wiki/President_of_Bangladesh,title->President of Bangladesh},{President}],
  > XMLElement[a,{href->/wiki/Nereo_Laroni,title->Nereo Laroni},{Nereo Laroni}],
  > XMLElement[a,{href->/wiki/Mayor_of_Venice,title->Mayor of Venice},{Mayor of Venice}], ...}
  > ```

### Things that should have(?) worked but don't!

- Combined pattern `pattn5`

  Evaluating `Cases[src, pattn5, Infinity]` evaluates to `{}`. Nothing gets matched!

### Suggestions, Nudges, Tips on how to get a decent match

Are all welcome.

Thanks!

---

### Appendix

I provide the [`src`](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/qNwBWfJ6) used throughout the question (*pastebin*). Run `Uncompress` on the string to retrieve the XML elements.

Comment: related to pastebin: 1. click on the link 2. when you are redirected, copy the text (place your cursor in the body of the text, select all the text and copy selection) 3. in a notebook type `Uncompress["` then paste in the contents of the clipboard and continue typing without moving the cursor `"]` 4. evaluate

Answer (score 2):

This answer will be about the section entitled

### Things that partially work

I got the input from the web (I was unable to use pastebin successfully).

```
xml = Import["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deaths_in_2019#July", "XML"];

pattn0 = XMLElement[
  "h3", _, {XMLElement["span",
     {"class" -> "mw-headline", "id" -> id_}, {idnm_}]}];

pos0 = Position[xml, pattn0];

pos1 = MapAt[# + 1 &, pos0, {All, -1}];

src = Apply[Part[xml, ##] &, Riffle[pos0, pos1], 1];
```

`src` changes with time so mine may not be identical to the data in pastebin.

Below are some example parts of `src` that serve as your data entries.

```
Column[src[[8, 3]][[1 ;; 2]], Dividers -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note carefully that it looks like you have multiple elements following the XMLElement. However if you check the `Head` you will find that it is a single string.

```
src[[8, 3, 3, 3, 2]]
(* ", 91, Vietnamese mathematician." *)

Head[src[[8, 3, 3, 3, 2]]]
(* String *)
```

### Patterns that match XML

You had set `pattn1` to

```
pattn1 = XMLElement["a", {"href" -> href_, Longest[othr___],
  "title" -> tit_, last___}, {nm_}]
```

When applied to `src` I got 576 entries

```
pattn1List = Cases[src, pattn1, Infinity];
```

Below is a sample of the result

```
Column[pattn1List[[1 ;; 3]], Dividers -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Patterns that match XML and comments

You had wanted to match both the XML and comments that might follow. You tried:

```
pattn2 = PatternSequence[pattn1, Longest[cmnt___]]
```

But when it is applied it to `src` you didn't get any comments. In fact, it was identical to only using `pattn1`.

```
pattn2List = Cases[src, pattn2, Infinity];

SameQ[pattn1List, pattn2List]
(* True *)
```

### PatternSequence

The documentation indicates that `PatternSequence` should not be used as a standalone pattern. `pattn2` violates that principle.

I will show two attempts that produce a result, however neither is the desired result.

**Failure 1**

```
pattn2 = {___, PatternSequence[pattn1, cmnt_String], ___}
pattn2List = Cases[src, pattn2, Infinity];
```

This produces a result but rather than individual entries it returns the entire list with interspersed XMLElements and comments. Below is an example.

```
pattn2List[[4]]

  (* {XMLElement[
  "a", {"href" -> "/wiki/Giuseppe_Merlo", 
   "title" -> "Giuseppe Merlo"}, {"Giuseppe Merlo"}],
   ", 91, Italian tennis player.", 
 XMLElement[
  "sup", {"id" -> "cite_ref-4", 
   "class" -> "reference"}, {XMLElement[
    "a", {"href" -> "#cite_note-4"}, {"[4]"}]}]} *)
```

**Failure 2**

In order to extract both the XMLElement and its associated comment I tried.

```
pattn2 = {___, group : PatternSequence[pattn1, cmnt_String], ___}
pattn2List = Cases[src, pattn2 :> group, Infinity];
```

This succeeded in the sense that an XMLElement and its associated comment were returned. However only the first element from a multi-element list was returned, the others were missing.

Below is a sample

```
Column[pattn2List[[57 ;; 62]], Dividers -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### XMElement and comment

Hopefully this answer has been helpful in achieving a better understanding of `PatternSequence`.

I could stop here but would also like to present a method for retrieving XMLElement that match `pattn1` along its associated comment. Note, not all XMLElements that match `pattn1` are followed by comments.

The strategy is to make a list of positions (`posPattn1`)that match `pattn1`.

Also make a list of positions (`posCmnt`) that are strings.

Iterate over `posPattn1`, increment the position by one and determine if it is a member of `posCmnt` (i.e., a string).

If it is, output both, otherwise only output the XMLElement.

```
posPattn1 = Position[src, pattn1];
posCmnt = Position[src, _String];

pattn2List  = Map[
   Module[
     {
      pos1 = #,
      pos2 = #,
      pat1,
      str2
      },
     pat1 = Extract[src, pos1];
     pos2[[-1]] = pos2[[-1]] + 1;
     str2 = If[
       MemberQ[posCmnt, pos2],
       Extract[src, pos2],
       Nothing
       ];
     {pat1, str2}
     ] &,
   posPattn1
   ];
```